# Custom Header not available in Laravel $request object

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, http-headers, laravel-5.4

I have a web application, where I am authenticating based on my custom token sent in headers as `API_TOKEN`. I am not sure about what is happening, after all the code digging I did in source (laravel)

Here is my middleware

```
protected $AUTH_HEADER = 'API_TOKEN';
protected $_RESPONSE = array('status' => false, 'message' => '', 'data' => array());

public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
  $response = $this->_RESPONSE;
  if($request->hasHeader($this->AUTH_HEADER)){
    $api_token = $request->header($this->AUTH_HEADER);
    try{
      $request->user = \App\User::where(['api_token' => $api_token])->firstOrFail();
      Auth::login($request->user);
      $response = $next($request);
    }catch(\Exception $exception){
      $response['status'] = false;
      $response['message'] = 'Invalid Token.';
    }
  }else{
    $response['status'] = false;
    $response['message'] = 'Unauthorized Request.';
  }

  // Lines ONLY I used for cross verification of availability of my header
  // $response['data'] = getallheaders();
  // $response['data'] = $_SERVER;
  return $response;
}
```

Here is a screenshot of my POST request, `api.easyinventory.com` is a custom virtual host which maps to my app

[image]

My routes are placed right as follow in `api.php` which by default will placed below route group under `api` prefix

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'product'], function(){
    Route::get('read', 'API\ProductController@read');
}
```

Coming to the problem, if I call `getallheaders()`, I can see my custom header as shown below

[image]

But in `$request`, I am not able to get it. I will be grateful for any lead on this issue.

My effort includes tracking down where these headers are actually `SET` in `$request` object, I checked `ServerBag.php` in Symfony source code

[Symfony ServerBag Class Method - getHeaders](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/ServerBag.php#L28).

If you look at this function `getHeaders`. It only adds selective headers in `headers` array, either with `Content` as starting string or starting with `HTTP_`. I tried passing my own header like `HTTP_API_TOKEN` but success :-(

Comment: Are you just trying to authenticate the user using `api_token`?

Comment: Actually yes,  BUT my question is regarding accessing a custom header value in `$request` object.

Comment: Oh ok. You are just trying to access custom headers. I thought you were trying to authenticate. Because laravel has an authentication out of the box for api_token. If that's what you want...

Comment: Yes, I am aware of that but scenario here is bit different

Answer (score 8):

Can you try with the global helper `request()`

```
request()->header('API_TOKEN'); //<-- manually passing the string first, for test purposes
```

**EDIT------------**
As OP mentioned in comment below :

We should access our header as Camel cased So sending it as `API-TOKEN` and accessing it as `request()->header('Api-Token');`

Comment: So silly of me, turned out to be a trivial issue. We should access our header as `Camel cased` So sending it as `API-TOKEN` and accessing it as `Api-Token` in middleware works. o__0

Comment: this comment should be the right answer "So sending it as API-TOKEN and accessing it as Api-Token in middleware works."

Comment: @FaroqKhan I added your comment as an edit to this Answer to help others that won't read all comments.

Comment: weird.. this worked for me.. i still dont understand how.